# tcpdf print option enable in pdf file codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf

```
$pdf->SetProtection($permissions=array('print', 'copy'),
$user_pass=$otp, $owner_pass=$otp, $mode=0, $pubkeys=null);
```

I have generated the PDF file using TCPDF in Codeigniter. Print option was enable by using above code but it's not working? Why? please help me.

Comment: can you paste code here? so that i can help you.

Comment: that the code for print option enable in PDF file(generation) $user_pass and $owner_pass same print option enabled in PDF file but when i click it not working
https://sourceforge.net/p/tcpdf/bugs/512/ by reffer this i do print option was enabled but not working

Comment: i posted code below, please follow this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
That is how pdf generates :

require_once('tcpdf_include.php');
// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Ken');
$pdf->SetTitle('Upgraded Images');
$pdf->SetSubject('Order Label');
$pdf->SetKeywords('upgraded images, PDF, ken greenle, upgradedimages.com, print label');

// set default header data
//$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 049', PDF_HEADER_STRING);

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins


// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();


/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *

IMPORTANT:
If you are printing user-generated content, tcpdf tag can be unsafe.
You can disable this tag by setting to false the K_TCPDF_CALLS_IN_HTML
constant on TCPDF configuration file.

For security reasons, the parameters for the 'params' attribute of TCPDF
tag must be prepared as an array and encoded with the
serializeTCPDFtagParameters() method (see the example below).

 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
$order_id = $_GET['order_id'];
/* get order details here*/
$sql = "select o.*,u.`first_name`,u.`last_name` from `tbl_orders` as o inner join `tbl_users` as u on o.`client_id` = u.`user_id` where o.`order_id` = '".$order_id."'";
$query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$customer_name = $result['first_name'].' '.$result['last_name'];
$order_number = $result['order_number'];
$instructions = $result['instructions'];
$product_return_option = $result['product_return_option'];
$number_of_packages = $result['number_of_packages'];
$order_date = date("jS F", strtotime($result['order_date']));
if($result['rush_service'] != '')
{
    $rush_service = 'RUSH';
}
else
{
    $rush_service = '';
}

/* end here */
$html = '
<div style="border:2px solid #222; padding-right:10px;">
<table cellpadding="0" border="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:14px;">
 <tr>
 <td>
    <table width="100%">
    <tr>
    <td align="left">
    <span style="color:#000; text-align: left; font-size:24px;text-transform: uppercase;max-width: 200px;"><strong>'.$customer_name.'</strong></span><br>
    </td>
    <td align="left">
    <br>
    <span style="color:#000; text-align: right; font-size:14px;"><strong>'.$order_number.'</strong></span><br>
    <span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span style="color:#000; text-align: right; font-size:14px;"><strong>'.$order_date.'</strong></span>
    <br>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
 </td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td>
    <table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td style="height:10px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="left" style="color:#000; text-align: left; #000;font-weight: bold; font-size:14px;">
    '.$instructions.'
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height:10px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
    <table width="100%">
    <tr>
    <td style="">

    <span style="color:#000; text-align: left; font-size:54px;"><strong>'.$rush_service.'</strong></span><br>
    </td>
    <td align="left" style="padding-right:20px;">
    <span style="color:#000; text-align: right; font-size:14px;"><strong>'.$product_return_option.'</strong></span><br>
    </td>
    <td align="left" style="padding-right:20px;">
    <span style="color:#000; text-align: right; font-size:14px;"><strong>['.$number_of_packages.']</strong></span><br>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
 </td>
 </tr>
  </table>
  </div>';


// output the HTML content
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, 0, true, 0);

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

// reset pointer to the last page
$pdf->lastPage();

// ---------------------------------------------------------

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('text.pdf', 'D');exit;
// D for download and when you write I it will get opened.
```

Comment: PDF file was generated but i want print option enable and click on print option whatever content prints.

Comment: according to thik link : [https://sourceforge.net/p/tcpdf/bugs/412/](https://sourceforge.net/p/tcpdf/bugs/412/)
your code must be of the latest version.

Comment: yes i got it.actually latest version code not supported "montserrat" font whenever we use this font print option was not working.Use "helvetica" font.it will working.....

Answer (score 0):

yes i got it.actually latest version code not supported "montserrat" font whenever we use this font print option was not working.Use "helvetica" font.it will working.